# Shopify data pulling into own database

Tags: database, google-play, shopify, extract, inventory

we are working on a datawarehouse project and need to pull data from our customer´s shopify database.
We want to analyse inventory stock quantity and stock value, also do market analysis, traffic analysis, top landing pages, conversions, revenues and others.
Shopify offers REST APIs for data pulling but not all our requirements can be fulfilled.

Our question are wether

- there is a plan we can order, like shopify partner plus or AdminAPI that allows data pulling all data fields?
- are there experiences in data pulling from shopify, deeper than the published REST API queries?

I am new to shopify requirements, that´s why my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that if it can solve your problem. Currently, our company uses an online tool called Acho Studio to retrieve Shopify data. It's like ETL tools that allow you to connect to Shopify and export data to somewhere. The difference is that the tool hosts a sever, so you can store data on it. Also, you can write SQL queries or apply some actions to do analysis.

Answer (score 0):

This is the codes snippet i am using

```
# Prepare headers 
headers = {}
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
headers["X-Shopify-Access-Token"] = f"{access_token}"

# Define the shopify url
shop_host = f'https://{hostName}.myshopify.com'
orderEndpoint = f'{order_endpoint}'

url = f'{shop_host}/{orderEndpoint}'
params = {'status': 'any',
          'limit': 250, 
          'created_at_min': '2022-01-01', 'created_at_max' : '2022-06-20'}
```

```
response = session.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=params)
orders = response.json()['orders']  # order data in json format

while 'next' in response.links:
    try:
        session = requests.Session()
        response = requests.get(response.links['next']['url'], headers=headers)
        orders.extend(response.json()['orders'])
    except KeyError as e:
        if response.links == 'next':
            print('go next page')
        else:
            print('No more pages')
```

I am able to pull the Order data and other data such as refund, .etc